# saving uuid (primary key) into postgres using hibernate dao?

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, uuid

I have a class `ABC` which contains a variable `id` which is of type `uuid` and is a primary key. I am using postgres to save the object, and in my DB `id` is of type `uuid`. When I am executing this code I am getting following error.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "event", schema = "public", uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "id"))
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS) 
public class ABC implements java.io.Serializable {
    @Type(type = "pg-uuid")
    private UUID  id;

    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid")
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    @Type(type = "pg-uuid")
    public UUID getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(UUID id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

Using main class to save object of ABC in postgres using hibernate:

```
ABCDAO dao = new ABCDAO();
ABC be = new ABC();
Session session = dao.getSession();
Transaction tx = null;
try {
    tx = session.beginTransaction();
    session.save(be);
    tx.commit();
} catch (HibernateException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    if (tx != null)
        tx.rollback();
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    session.close();
}
```

The error:

```
org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: IllegalArgumentException occurred while calling setter of com.istarindia.apps.dao.IstarEvent.id
    at org.hibernate.property.BasicPropertyAccessor$BasicSetter.set(BasicPropertyAccessor.java:119)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.setIdentifier(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:384)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.setIdentifier(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4555)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:182)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:135)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:208)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:151)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:78)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:772)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:746)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:750)
    at istar.TestDB.main(TestDB.java:105)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.hibernate.property.BasicPropertyAccessor$BasicSetter.set(BasicPropertyAccessor.java:65)
    ... 11 more
org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: IllegalArgumentException occurred while calling setter of com.istarindia.apps.dao.IstarEvent.id
    at org.hibernate.property.BasicPropertyAccessor$BasicSetter.set(BasicPropertyAccessor.java:119)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.setIdentifier(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:384)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.setIdentifier(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4555)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:182)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:135)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:208)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:151)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:78)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:772)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:746)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:750)
    at istar.TestDB.main(TestDB.java:105)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.hibernate.property.BasicPropertyAccessor$BasicSetter.set(BasicPropertyAccessor.java:65)
    ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 0):

got it resolved, changed the getter, setter and annotations like this

```
@javax.persistence.Id
@GenericGenerator(name = "uuid-gen", strategy = "uuid2")
@GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid-gen")
@org.hibernate.annotations.Type(type="pg-uuid")
public UUID getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(UUID value) {
    this.id = value;
}
```